# Login using AJAX vs complete form submission (reload complete page)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, authentication

I have a login form. 
I want to know if using AJAX for login purpose or sending the complete form will be better, both in terms of security and performance?

I intend to make AJAX call as it prevents the page reload when the inputs provided are invalid instead of loading a complete page.
What to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with an AJAX-Post (keeping the url-cache clean of user-submitted data), just as long as you have a fallback (for users with javascript disabled). Especially since it is a logon-system.
On the other hand.. if your web-service (the thing/content you are 'selling') fully depends on javascript (like a browser game), then you can forget about that common-sense requirement.

As to performance: yes, it usually is faster since you only communicate a couple of bytes with the (backend-)server.

**Edit:** optionally you could try to obfuscate/hash the data (username/password) you are sending (since all code required to do that would be in the javascript, there will however never be any *real* security to that, use SSL to add an extra layer of security).

Hope this helps